# View diff of css changes made from dev tools

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, diff, web-inspector

Is there an easy way to view a diff of changes I make to the css on a page? I find myself making a bunch of changes to see how things look in dev tools, but when I go into my codebase to make the changes I often don't remember all the details I changed.